# All registered dll in the system in .net

Tags: .net, asp.net, dll, operating-system, dllregistration

Is it possible in .NET to get a list of all registered dll in Windows OS. Can anyone provide me with C# code.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by registered DLLs? Do you mean COM dlls or something else?

Comment: See this newer question (more details) with an accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767002/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-unmanaged-dlls-which-were-registered-by-regsvr32-too