# How can I get a list of all unmanaged dlls which were registered by regsvr32 tool?

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I use regsvr32 to register and unregister unmanaged DLL's to use it in my C# application. But I did not see any parameter in the regsvr32 tool that lists all registered DLL's, so how can I get a list of all registered DLL's?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To view all the registered DLLs you can use the following free utilities:

1. [RegDllView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registered_dll_view.html) is a tool to view registered dll/ocx/exe files on your system and can also Register dll files from Explorer.
2. [ListDLLs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656) is another tool that reports the DLLs loaded into processes. You can use it to list all DLLs loaded into all processes, into a specific process, or to list the processes that have a particular DLL loaded. ListDLLs can also display full version information for DLLs, including their digital signature, and can be used to scan processes for unsigned DLLs.
3. Finally, you can also refer to this [Dll Profiler in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3980/Dll-Profiler-in-C) article on CodeProject.com.
   **DLL profiler** is used list all the DLLs that are currently loaded in your machine, including where they are loaded and their version number, size, modification date, product name and product version.

Comment: Just a note not to panic if RegDllView looks like it is "hung" on startup because its window contents do no get updated when you drag the window around. It is working! And it occasionally gives a number of DLLs found, so give it a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey(v=vs.100).aspx) to read all the Registered [CLSID's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691424(v=vs.85).aspx) in the `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID`.  Haven't looked at 32-bit Windows to see where the `CLSIDs` are.

Comment: How do you use this method? Although I have register a few DLLs with the `regsvr32` command, under the path you mentioned, there is only one default item. so how do I use your method to view the registered DLLs ?

Answer (score 2):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var parent = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("CLSID");
    var subKeys = parent.GetSubKeyNames();
    foreach (var subKey in subKeys)
    {
        var sub = parent.OpenSubKey(subKey);
        if (sub != null)
        {
            var inProc = sub.OpenSubKey("InProcServer32");
            if (inProc != null)
            {
                var val = inProc.GetValue(null);
                if (val != null)
                {
                    var name = val.ToString();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                        Console.WriteLine(name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, viewing the InProcServer32 value will often (always?) get you the 8.3 filename for the dll, so you may want to also capture the ProgID subkey (when available) and/or lookup the long filename.

Comment: Does this method return both 32 bit and 64 bit registered dlls?