# How to create COM object from .dll file?

Tags: dll, vbscript, dllimport

I'm trying to open a DLL file `blabla.dll`. The problem is that I dont know what class and methods are inside that file. I didn't succeded breaking through the DLL to get that info. I received the DLL from a company I'm working with and they dont know the names either.

I tried:

```
set kgobj = CreateObject("blabla.someClassName")
```

and

```
set kgobj = CreateObject("blabla")
```

but in both cases recieved

> Error : on WriteLog-
>   ActiveX component can't create object

I saw almost every post here and on Google but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 3):

Could you be more specific about the solutions you tried?

First, you didn't specify if the dll was registered. It needs to be registered with regsvr32.exe on your machine to be callable via CreateObject.

Then check this post, it should give you ways of listing the classes in your dll: [How can I get a list of all unmanaged dlls which were registered by regsvr32 tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767002/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-unmanaged-dlls-which-were-registered-by-regsvr32-too)